# Proxy Configuration for C# GraphSdk

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, http-proxy

I need to relay the HTTP-Requests made by the C# Graph-Sdk over a proxy.

In the documentation I could not find any information about proxy settings.
The only workaraound I currently found is to change the global proxy settings:

```
System.Net.GlobalProxySelection.Select = proxy;
or
System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;
```

Sadly in my situation this is not possible without moving all graph 
related features into a separate process (as the rest of the main-process needs to run without proxy).

So my Question is:

- Is there any official support for Proxy Settings in the sdk?
- And is support for Proxy Settings planned for future sdk-versions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the proxy when you instantiate your GraphServiceClient.

**Update 6/9/2021**

There is now a better way by using the GraphClientFactory.

```
HttpClient httpClient = GraphClientFactory.Create(GetClientCredentialProvider(), "v1.0", "Global", new WebProxy(""));
var graphServiceClient = new(httpClient);
```

**Old answer**

```
System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler()
{
    AllowAutoRedirect = false,
    Proxy = new WebProxy() // TODO: Set your proxy settings. 
};

HttpProvider httpProvider = new HttpProvider(httpClientHandler, true);

GraphServiceClient client = new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
            async (requestMessage) =>
            {
                var token = await goGetSomeTokenNow();
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);

            }), httpProvider);
```

Comment: Hi Is there a Java equivalent?

Comment: @sh4r4d Do you mean to ask whether there is a Java equivalent library or way to set the proxy? Yes to both.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new way for Microsoft.Graph 4+ in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/customize-client?tabs=csharp) article. Yet I had to achieve this using mix of two ways due to our azure adfs only auth requests are coming from browsers. Hope this will help full to others.

```
private GraphServiceClient GetGraphClient()
{
    string[] scopes = new string[] { "User.Read", "User.ReadBasic.All", "Mail.Read", "Mail.ReadWrite", "Mail.Send" };

    var msalFactory = new MsalHttpClientFactoryOwn(_configuration);

    IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create("")
    .WithTenantId("")
    .WithHttpClientFactory(msalFactory)
    .Build();

    UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);

    HttpClient httpClient = GraphClientFactory.Create(authProvider, "v1.0", "Global", msalFactory.GetWebProxy());
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(httpClient);
    
    return graphClient;
}

public class MsalHttpClientFactoryOwn : IMsalHttpClientFactory
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public ProxiedHttpClientFactory(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        var proxyHttpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() 
        { 
            UseProxy = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = GetNetworkCredentials(),
            Proxy = GetWebProxy()
        };

        var httpClient = new HttpClient(proxyHttpClientHandler);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");
        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

        return httpClient;
    }

    public WebProxy GetWebProxy()
    {
        var proxy = new WebProxy
        {
            Address = new Uri("proxy address"),
            BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = GetNetworkCredentials()
        };

        return proxy;
    }

    private NetworkCredential GetNetworkCredentials()
    {
        var networkCreds =  new NetworkCredential(u, p);
        return networkCreds;
    }
}
```